Add space within two variables in ng-div
I need to add space between empName and empId.
Since single quote and double quotes are already used, I am not able to put a space here. Can someone please help
<div <h6 ng-bind="empName +empId"> class="modal-body scrollable" </h6></div>\n

I tried using $nbsp. But it did not work

Just do empName + ' ' + empId in ng-bind:


<div>
    <h6 ng-bind="empName + ' ' + empId" class="modal-body scrollable"></h6>
</div>




adding a space using ' ' will work
<h6 ng-bind="empName + ' ' + empId"></h6>


To add a space between empName and empId in the ng-bind directive in AngularJS, you can use a template literal (backticks) to construct the string, which allows for easier concatenation and inclusion of spaces.
Here’s how you can do it:
<h6 ng-bind="`${empName} ${empId}`" class="modal-body scrollable"></h6>

However, if you're constrained to using double quotes within the ng-bind attribute and cannot use template literals, you can concatenate the variables with a space string:
<h6 ng-bind="empName + ' ' + empId" class="modal-body scrollable"></h6>

